# When formulating and performing experiments for quantum theory do physicists account for us constantly moving through non-zero energy vacuum?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, relative-motion, quantum-measurements

Problem: If we suppose that each smallest possible point in vacuum is a size of Planck length and that point is somehow affecting that particle with spontaneously emerging non-zero energy, then as our entire reference point is moving through vacuum at substantial speed it could potentially seriously affect those measurements.

In turn could this formulation of non-zero energy of vacuum be in fact result of our macro system moving through vacuum and we are observing different points in vacuum being populated by our system's particles?

One could argue that we never ever observe same point in vacuum, since our galaxy is cruising through space and we don't really know what happens second ago since that point in vacuum is hundreds of miles away after one second.

Comment: why google it? I'm already there..

Comment: The “Planck constant” is very different from the Planck volume.

Comment: @G.Smith thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your question asks about accounting for the Earth's, Sun's, and Milky Way's speed. The principle of relativity says these don't matter. That's because the laws of physics should be the same for *every* observer, no matter where they are or how fast they're moving.

If we did have to take into account that the Earth is moving (for this experiment), then that's the same as saying that different observers need different laws of physics. To see this, let's assume that we make no corrections, and measure a certain value X. Now we move from the Earth to Mars, we do the same experiment, and again make no corrections. Since we're now on Mars (which moves around the Sun at a different speed), we should get a different result. That's what's meant when we say different observers need different laws of physics. In fact we don't even need to do this - we can just change locations on Earth and we should see different results (because different points on Earth rotate at different speeds).

Empirically we do not see different results, which is why we believe in the principle of relativity, and also why we do not need to make corrections.

Comment: Thanks you for taking time and answering this question. I think in this case particles that we observe are moving through a medium ( non-zero energy vacuum ) and that could seriously affect measurements. 

What's I'm saying is that relativity principles do not apply to quantum particles, they are not a macro system.

Comment: @farid I think you're incorrect. All the particles we already observe are moving through a medium (air) and that doesn't change any laws of physics.

Comment: @farid principle of relativity applies to everything, including macro systems. If you think they don't, you're thinking about non-mainstream physics.

Comment: I could be wrong, don't want to spew bs. However reading this: https://cosmosmagazine.com/physics/a-step-closer-to-a-theory-of-quantum-gravity

specifically:
Quantum physics has very successfully described the behaviour of tiny particles such as atoms and electrons, while relativity is very accurate for forces at cosmic scales. However, in some cases, notably gravity, the two theories produce incompatible results.

Comment: also this: https://www.quora.com/Does-quantum-physics-include-the-theory-of-relativity

Comment: @farid that's the theory of relativity, which is not the same as the principle of relativity.

Comment: thank you for clarification. I'm not suggesting that laws are different for observers, what I'm suggesting is that as particles are moving through non-zero energy vacuum they get affected and we aren't accounting for that when formulating  those laws.

Comment: @farid comes to the same thing. Because of the Earth's rotation, if what you think is correct an experiment performed on the equator (which has a "faster" speed) will yield different results from one performed on the North Pole, i.e. the laws are different for different observers. That's a violation of the principle of relativity.

Comment: @safesphere I'd go further than that. The principle of relativity is in every physical law. If the laws of physics varied with position, we wouldn't have conservation of momentum; if they varied with time, we wouldn't have conservation of energy (both these statements come from Noether's theorem).

Comment: @Allure I'm not suggesting that laws of physics are different as we move through space. I'm suggesting that we are not accounting for an effect of particles interacting with non-zero vacuum energy as we are moving through space.

Comment: @farid the logical conclusion of that - of particles interacting with non-zero vacuum energy as we are moving through space - is that the laws of physics are different for different observers. I'm going to edit the answer to make that clearer.

Comment: @allure thank you and thanks for being patient :D Again I don't think about this as different laws for different observers. More like currently formulated laws aren't accounting for it. Little more on this and where I'm coming from with this question: https://medium.com/nakshatra/the-nature-of-nothingness-understanding-the-vacuum-catastrophe-c04033e752f4

Comment: @farid I don't see how that article is relevant at all. This is fundamentally a question about the principle of relativity, not quantum field theory. Please try to understand what I'm saying. *By claiming that we need to correct for the Earth's motion, you are also claiming that the laws of physics are different on Mars*. Once you understand where this statement is coming from, then we can continue.

Comment: @allure you are right, I should re-phrase the question. Speed isn't important here. What's important is the fact that we are constantly moving through vacuum which can have non-zero energy. Thanks again!

Comment: @farid I don't see why it would matter then - if that zero-point energy is everywhere, that includes where you're moving from to where you're moving to, in which case any effect cancels.

Answer (score 0):

Everything we currently know about physics, including quantum physics, implies that it is not possible to have a physical phenomenon which depends on a system's velocity relative to another system with which it is not interacting. This means, in particular, that the influence of the local vacuum near to any system is not detectable through velocity, but it may be detectable through acceleration. So, to put it in simple terms, you can't tell whether you have a velocity relative to the vacuum, but you can tell whether you have an acceleration relative to any local inertial frame, so if you like you can say that you can tell if you have an acceleration relative to the vacuum. Most physicists would judge the inertial frame way of putting it to be better, however, because it is a statement that can be defined in more formal and precise terms, but it is hard to say what one means by motion relative to the vacuum.

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. If we consider each smallest (Planck scale ) point in vacuum as a 3d coordinate and this point has non-zero energy, then what happens when let's say a photon enters that point? Does that vacuum point morph into that particle? Or particle simply replaces that vacuum point temporarily? What happens with that non-zero energy? Is there an interaction with a particle entering that vacuum point?

Comment: @safesphere Thanks for bringing that up, I remember worldlines from Feynman lectures ;) But the question remains: does non-zero quantum energy affect particles as they pass through vacuum and if yes then how?

Comment: @safesphere I found a very good partial answer to my question here as well: https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/are-virtual-particles-rea/

There is also an interesting mention here about temporary violation of conservation of energy principle: 
"Quantum mechanics allows, and indeed requires, temporary violations of conservation of energy, so one particle can become a pair of heavier particles (the so-called virtual particles), which quickly rejoin into the original particle as if they had never been there."